# Computing $\langle x\rangle$ for state in infinite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, wavefunction, probability

We are given a state $$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\phi_1(x)+\phi_3(x))$$

where the $\phi_i$'s are eigenstates corresponding to the infinite potential well case. I was wondering if $$\langle x \rangle=\langle \psi^*\vert x\psi\rangle=\int_0^a\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\phi_1(x)+\phi_3(x))\bigg)x\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\phi_1(x)+\phi_3(x))\bigg)dx$$

is the correct way to compute the expected value. It turns out that $$\langle x \rangle =\frac{a}{2}$$

in this instance. Does this result make sense?

Comment: Your $\psi$ is normalized iff the $\phi_j$ are orthogonal. If so, you need to complex-conjugate one of the $\psi$ factors. I've edited in the $x$ factor you omitted but presumably knew about, given that your $\langle x\rangle$ estimate is of the correct dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you have done is correct. Just note two points:

1. You didn't take the complex conjugate of $\phi_i$ since in the infinite potential well they are real. This is a special case it will not generally be so.
2. For a generalization of your result, note that for $n,m$ both odd or both even $\int_0^a \phi_m(x) \phi_n(x) x = 0$. Since the expectation value of $\langle n | x | n \rangle = \frac{a}{2}$ for all eigenstates $|n\rangle$ it will remain exactly this value for any superposition of only even or only odd $n$'s.

Comment: Please do not encourage users to post elementary homework questions by providing them with answers.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that can you point me to the guidelines, I am new to this :)

Comment: No worries.  Check https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange and https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic